# Get a string out of Linq query result

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to make a bot which search the web for a specific term and stuff like that, in this case the webpage is duckduckgo; I have the Linq code which is this:

```
        internal async Task<IEnumerable<SearchResult>> Search(string query)
    {
        string xml = await new WebClient()
        .DownloadStringTaskAsync($"http://api.duckduckgo.com/?q={query}&format=xml");
        var root = XElement.Parse(xml);

        return root.Descendants("RelatedTopic").Take(1)
            .Select(t => new SearchResult
            {
                Text = t.Element("Text")?.Value
            });
    }

    internal class SearchResult
    {
        internal string Text { get; set; }
    }
```

And I'm trying to convert the result into a string so that I can send the link to a chat as, well, a string. I'm not having any issues with the code overall; I just want to know how I'd do that. That's the whole code; nothing more is interfering with it.

Comment: could I solve your problem?

Comment: @rbr94 excuse me for not replying; the thing was that Text was already a string so there was no reason to do that again but since I'm a beginner I didn't know I could use ToString() to something else in the code so I picked it as a correct answer anyway :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Object.ToString()` method:

```
Text = t.Element("Text")?.Value?.ToString();
```

Comment: `ToString()` is directly implemented in `Object` - not an extension method.

Comment: I have changed that.

Comment: If you prefer `null` over a `NullReferenceException`, make that `?.ToString()`.

Comment: @TomBlodget Isn't it catched with `Element("Text")?` already?

Comment: Yes, it does in that part of the expression. If there is no element, then the access to Value is conditional. There is still the call to `ToString` to consider.

Comment: @TomBlodget I changed that in my post